# Delete multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

I want to delete all records in table participant_vote where the id matches the id of another table row.

Can this be done in one query?

This is the query I have now which returns the error that my subselect contains multiple rows

> DELETE FROM `participant_vote` WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM `vote` WHERE
>   `facebookid` = :facebookid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM participant_vote WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM vote WHERE facebookid = :facebookid)
```

`IN` being the trick. My feeling is that searching for the message would also have provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use the `IN` operator instead of the `=` operator.

```
DELETE FROM participant_vote
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM vote
    WHERE facebookid = :facebookid
)
```